# vlookup google sheets first and last name compare

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Okay so i have a this formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"Manager:";IF(D5:D="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&REGEXEXTRACT(D5:D,"[a-zA-Z]+")&"*",'Client-Manager'!A:B,2,FALSE),"NO MATCH"))})`

It works fine with what i have it doing now but i'm running into a problem now were i need to compare both last and first name and i can't figure out how to do it.

Here is an example sheet:

[Sheet im working with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mni1bBqwXxVUNzM5bfWQGhfGTrsnUAeL-T_KytJk-UU/edit?usp=sharing)

Im comparing in "work-order" sheet column D with and in "manager" sheet column A to then output back on "work-order" sheet column G.

Formula i'm working with resides in "Manager" cell in "work-order" sheet in column G

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I agree with player0. You've essentially shown us a one-inch close-up of a nose, an eye and and some fur and asked us to guess the animal. If you need to, make a copy of your spreadsheet, strip it down to enough data to illustrate the issue, and replace any sensitive data with realistic dummy data that is as close in form and format to the actual data as possible.

Comment: @player0 I have added spreadsheet im working with. Thank you

Comment: @ErikTyler I have added spreadsheet im working with. Thank you

Comment: can you point out row where your formula fails?

Comment: Ismar, you said in your post, "i'm running into a problem now were i need to compare both last and first name." Can you give a specific example of a row in the 'Work Order' sheet that currently illustrates this problem?

Comment: @ErikTyler If your scroll down to rows 47-50 you can see that it has matched the manager to Kevin even though it should be Raj because it's only comparing the last name and not the first name as well.

Comment: @player0 If your scroll down to rows 47-50 you can see that it has matched the manager to Kevin even though it should be Raj because it's only comparing the last name and not the first name as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Manager:"; IF(D5:D="",,
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(D5:D, ",", ), 
 "[a-zA-Z ]+")&"*", 'Client-Manager'!A:B, 2, ), 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&REGEXEXTRACT(D5:D, 
 "[a-zA-Z]+")&"*", 'Client-Manager'!A:B, 2, ), "NO MATCH")))})
```

[image]